# Como insere imagens em um arquivo XML?

Tags: xml, imagem

Olá,possuo um arquivo em xml, e gostaria de saber como introduz uma imagem dentro dele, alguém poderia ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O XML é praticamente um formato baseado em texto, o que significa que você não poderá "ver a imagem" em seu documento XML.

Você pode transformar a imagem em **Base64** e incorporar a string no XML.

**UPDATE**

**Primeiro**, você transforma a imagem em Base64 aqui: https://www.base64-image.de/

**Depois** só colar dentro da div img `<img>data:image/png;base64,....</img>` o código do site acima.

Comment: não sou boa com xml, não poderia simplificar oque disse?

Comment: Que linguagem usa? Só precisa de uma imagem ou vai ser função?

Comment: apenas imagem, é para um projeto em mobile

Comment: N esquece de avaliar :) boa sorte, abs